# How to make a site responisve with tailwind and react

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, responsive

icreated a blog and i wnat to make it responsive. By default i would like that it has a dropdown menu within a mobile device on the right site with about new profile and logut. on the other site when its on Desktop mode i would like that in the middle there is the about new and profile and on the right just the logout button.

this is the code i have so faar. i worked with lg: to make it responsive when its bigger then desktop.

If i made some grammerly mistakes or misspeled anything, i apologize infront. English is not my first language.

``import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useUserContext } from './UserProvider';`

function Navbar() {

const { user, setUser } = useUserContext()

function logout() {
localStorage.removeItem('user')
setUser(null)

}

return (

Tech-Blog

```
  <div className=" NavLinks  bg-pink-100 flex flex-col absolute top-10 right-0 p-4 lg:flex-row  ">
    <div className="Links
    flex flex-col
     lg:flex-row lg:absolute lg:left-1/2 lg:top-1/2 lg:transform md:-translate-x-1/2 lg:-translate-y-1/2  text-2xl lg:justify-between lg:w-60   " >
      <div className='hover:cursor-pointer '>About</div>
      <div className='hover:cursor-pointer '>Profile</div>
      <Link to="/new">New</Link>
    </div>
    <div className='buttons flex md:flex-row md:absolute lg:right-8 lg:top-1 lg:gap-6  '>

      {/* check if someone is loged in if yes then show us a logout button */}
      {user === null ?
        <> <Link to="/login" ><button className='bg-blue-400 px-4 rounded-md py-2 text-white'>SignIn</button></Link>
          <Link to="/register" ><button className='bg-blue-400 px-4 rounded-md py-2 text-white'> Register</button></Link> </> :
        <button className='bg-blue-400 px-4 rounded-md py-2 text-white font-mono' onClick={logout}>Log out </button>}

    </div>


  </div>



</div>
```

)
}

export default Navbar
`

i tryied to change some thing in tailwind with lg: and some other things

Answer (score 2):

To make it responsive you have to utilize Tailwind css properties "sm:", "md:", "lg:" "xl:".
You can control all styles using these for different viewport sizes. For guidance you can see their documentation about responsiveness. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design